# RichTextBox not typeable in between

Tags: c#, winforms, richtextbox

I color a text in `richtextbox` but after that I cannot type anything in between that text, using this code, what is the problem ? In the string below `2,3,4,9,22,92` I am not able to write anything in between it writes all after this string.

```
richTextBox1.Text = "2,3,4,9,22,92";
richTextBox1.SelectionStart = 0;
richTextBox1.SelectionLength = richTextBox1.Text.Length;
richTextBox1.SelectionColor = Color.Green;
```

Comment: Tested and can't see anything wrong here.

Comment: Are you sure this is the full code?

Comment: This code is working ... May b issue is at some other side.. Did you set some property of RichTextBox? Do one thing, remove the existing control/Add a new control, and use same code for that without changing the properties.. Probably you will get the bug..

Comment: did you set the `ReadOnly` property to true?

Comment: What do you mean by 'writing'?? Adding text in code or typing at runtime?

Comment: you guys are right I think the problem is in other section of the code which is not directly applying to it.